# Is "e" always pronounced like /e/ before ss?

Tags: prononciation, voyelles

I've mistakenly used /ə/ rather than /e/ in ***e**ssayer*, *prof**e**sseur*, ***e**ssentiel*. Is "ess" always /es/?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either /e/ or /ɛ/ but very rarely /ə/ indeed. This is true for every *E* located before any double consonant. Despite the accented pronunciation, there is never an actual acute, grave or circumflex accent on these E's, no exception.

On the other hand, there are a few words of this kind where the *E* is pronounced /ə/ like *cresson* in some regions.

A larger group of exceptions is composed of words having the prefixes *de-* or *re-* and where the double consonant is only there to keep the pronunciation of the unprefixed root:

- *dessus* (a hypothetical *desus* would tend to be pronounced /dəzy/)
- *dessous*
- *ressac*
- *ressembler*
- *ressentir*
- *ressortir*
  ...

Other exceptions:

- *Montpellier* (except locally where it is pronounced /mɔ̃pelje/)
- *prunellier*
- *travelling*
- *ardennais* (locally)

Comment: There are a few local exceptions, like 'cresson' for instance (a type of salad) which is pronounced with an /ə/ in some regions but this rule is valid most of the time.

Comment: @vc74 C'est vrai, et il y en a deux ou trois autres, merci !